# How to ensure gsutil copy does not use external Internet?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, gsutil, google-vpc

I have a Minecraft server I built on GCP using [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/gaming/minecraft-server).  It is running on GCP `us-central1-f` (Iowa) , with a regional storage bucket on `us-central1` (Iowa).  I have a cronjob set to run a bash script to back up the world files (about 2GB) every 4 hours to the bucket using `gsutil`.  This is the backup script:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME=$(date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")-world.tar.gz 

screen -r mcs -X stuff 'save-all flush\nsave-off\n'
tar -zcvf /home/minecraft/$FILENAME /home/minecraft/world /home/minecraft/world_nether /home/minecraft/world_the_end
/usr/bin/gsutil cp /home/minecraft/$FILENAME gs://path-to-bucket-minecraft-backup/$FILENAME 
screen -r mcs -X stuff 'save-on\n'
rm /home/minecraft/$FILENAME
```

I've been running this way for about a month, and I noticed I was being charged for hundreds of GB of external network egress, and with only 5-10 users on the Minecraft server.  I contacted GCP Support, and they confirmed the network data is the transfers to the storage bucket, which is apparently going over the Internet.  Their recommendation was to configure Private Google Access to use `gsutil`.

I worked with another GCP Support rep to try to do this:

- We edited the server VM instance and set "Cloud API access scopes" to "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs"
- We went into the Default VPC Network and enabled "Private Google Access" for `us-central1`.
- We disabled the external IP, and confirmed that I was able to copy files to the storage bucket, so it is possible for the backup to run over the internal network.

According to the documentation on [Configuring Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access), A VM with an external IP address assigned to its network interface doesn't need Private Google Access to connect to Google APIs and services.  GCP Support didn't have a way to tell if the backup traffic would now go over the internal or external link.  They pointed me to Stack Overflow for help.

So I guess my question is, what do I need to do to ensure my backups using `gsutil cp ...` are transferred over the internal network, and don't go over the internet?  Do I need to adjust routing?  I've read through the [documentation on `gsutil`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil), and I haven't found anything on how to specify how the traffic flows.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation :

[Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options)

> VM instances that **only have internal IP addresses** (no external IP
> addresses) can use Private Google Access. They can reach the external
> IP addresses of Google APIs and services. ...
>
> Private Google Access **has no effect on instances that have external
> IP** addresses. Instances with external IP addresses can access the
> internet, according to the internet access requirements. They don't
> need any special configuration to send requests to the external IP
> addresses of Google APIs and services.

Therefore, I believe that you can use gsutil over the internal network only if your VM has internal IP address.